# getting nested json objects in spark

Tags: apache-spark

below is my json printschema , want to print all records where id > 1268431 , id is string here.

```
|-- results: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- total: long (nullable = true)
|-- result: string (nullable = true)
```

i was trying to use the below command:

```
 val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("select results.id from people where results.id > 1268431 ").collect().foreach(println);
```

please help.

Comment: Please specify the code for parsing the JSON and creating the `people` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following JSON Structure: -

```
{"results": 
   [{"name":"x","id":"1"}, 
    {"name":"y","id":"2"}], 
 "total":"20", "result":30
}
```

Here is the way you would query and apply filters on the JSON Nested Structures using Spark-SQL: -

```
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("<file PATH>")
df.registerTempTable("people")
df.printSchema()

//Here is the SQL Query which Filters the results on the values provided in Nested Schema using LATERAL VIEWS and explode function.
sqlContext.sql("select expResults.id,expResults.name from people LATERAL VIEW explode(results)people AS expResults where int(expResults.id) > 1").collect().foreach(println)
```

The Output of the above code would be the following values printed on the console: -

```
[2,y]
```